Changing default background image in specific pages (XeLaTeX)
I have a default background image for my document, but I need a different background on specific pages. Atm the only thing I was able to do is to have both the backgrounds, while I need to momentarily disable the default and implement the alternative. I'm attaching the default img
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PREAMBOLO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[        paperwidth=139.7mm, 
                            paperheight=215.9mm, 
                            textwidth=101mm,    
                            inner=20mm,         
                top=26mm,
                bottom=26mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background}
\usepackage{fontspec}                               


\begin{document}


\AddToHook{shipout/background}{
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}
    {\put(+0mm,-214mm){\includegraphics[width=1.4\textwidth]{frame.png}}} % pagina dx
    {\put(-1.1mm,-214mm){\includegraphics[width=1.4\textwidth]{frame.png}}}  % pagina sx
}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
Here I would like to have a different background\\

\lipsum[2]

\clearpage
And here I want to go back to the default background\\

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}




\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\myimage{example-image-A}
\begin{document}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
 \put(+0mm,-214mm){\includegraphics[width=1.4\textwidth]{\myimage}}}

\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\renewcommand\myimage{example-image-B}
Here I would like to have a different background\\

\lipsum[2]

\clearpage
\renewcommand\myimage{example-image-A}
And here I want to go back to the default background\\

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}

